# Python Anti Vowel Program

Tags: python

I'm learning Python on codeacademy and I'm stuck on a program:

> Define a function called anti_vowel that takes one string, text, as input and returns the text with all of the vowels removed.
>   For example: `anti_vowel("Hey You!")` should return `"Hy Y!"`.
>   Don't count Y as a vowel.
>   Make sure to remove lowercase and uppercase vowels.

I created the program and I don't see any way that it's wrong but I get this error code:

> Oops, try again. Your function fails on `anti_vowel("Hey look Words!")`. It returns `"Hy lk Words!"` when it should return `"Hy lk Wrds!"`.*

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Here's the code:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    newText = ""
    tList = []
    for char in text:
        tList.append(char)
    for item in tList:
        if item in "aeiouAEIOU":
            tList.remove(item)
    for thing in tList:
        newText += thing
    return newText
```

Comment: See the duplicate; you are skipping characters in the list because you are altering the list while you loop.

Comment: `return text.translate(None, "aeiouAEIOU")` is enough in Python 2; in Python 3 use `text.translate(text.maketrans('', '', "aeiouAEIOU"))`.